# Is it possible to debug rml in eclipse IDE or with some other tools?

Tags: odoo

I am working with conditions and loopings in rml, where i essentially require to debug to fix some logical bugs. Is there a way to debug rml code (specifically with eclipse IDE). Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

No,  there is no direct way to debug rml.